# bug in NHunspell spelling checker

Tags: c#

I am using NHunspell for checking spelling.I added NHunspell.dll as a reference to my asp.net page.I added the namespace System.NHunspell.
The problem i am facing is related to IDisposible.
I put the downloaded code of NHunspell inside the button event.

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

```
        using (Hunspell hunspell = new Hunspell("en_us.aff", "en_us.dic"))
        {
            bool correct = hunspell.Spell("Recommendation");
            var suggestions = hunspell.Suggest("Recommendatio");
            foreach (string suggestion in suggestions)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Suggestion is: " + suggestion);
            }
        }

        // Hyphen
        using (Hyphen hyphen = new Hyphen("hyph_en_us.dic"))
        {
            var hyphenated = hyphen.Hyphenate("Recommendation");
        }


*  using (MyThes thes = new MyThes("th_en_us_new.idx", "th_en_us_new.dat"))
        {
            using (Hunspell hunspell = new Hunspell("en_us.aff", "en_us.dic"))
            {
                ThesResult tr = thes.Lookup("cars", hunspell);
                foreach (ThesMeaning meaning in tr.Meanings)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("  Meaning: " + meaning.Description);
                    foreach (string synonym in meaning.Synonyms)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("    Synonym: " + synonym);

                    }
                }
            }


        }
```

The * shown above is the line of error.The error is:
" type used in a using statement must be implicitly convertible to 'System.IDisposable'".

Also there is a warning on that line :"'NHunspell.MyThes.MyThes(string, string)' is obsolete: 'idx File is not longer needed, MyThes works completely in memory'";

Can any one help me to correct this???

ok, I changed that line to MyThes thes = new MyThes("th_en_us_new.dat"); bug is gone.

But there is an exception "AFF File not found: E:\programfiles\visual studio\Common7\IDE\en_us.aff". what i should do??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try changing the line to:

```
MyThes thes = new MyThes("th_en_us_new.dat");
```

Have you done a search for the en_us.aff file on your C:\ drive? In your original zipped download of NHunspell, you should find this file. It might just be enough for you to copy that file into the E:\programfiles\visual studio\Common7\IDE\ directory.

Comment: Downloaded NHunspell contains only NHunspell.dll,NHunspellx64.dll,NHunspellx86.dll.

Comment: If you are a member of CodeProject, download the zip file from http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/hunspell-for-net.aspx

Comment: now one more exception:"Hunspell Intel 32Bit DLL not found: C:\Documents and Settings\Nikhil K\My Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\splee\splee\Hunspellx86.dll".

line :"using (Hunspell hunspell = new Hunspell("en_us.aff","en_us.dic"))".

please help me..

Comment: Rason: I've changed MyThes from a wrapper to a completely managed version. So the IDisposable stuff isn't necessary anymore

Comment: anything better than  HUNSPELL ?

Answer (score 0):

don't use `using` then, if `MyThes` doesn't support `IDisposable`. For `Obsolete` - press F12 on `MyThes` and pick constructor without obsolete attribute

Comment: anything better than hunspell?